# Check if $M = \{z \in \mathbb{C}| z = \frac {1}{n} + \frac {i}{m} \ with \ \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \} \} $ is compact

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, compactness

I want to check, if this set is compact:

$M = \{z \in \mathbb{C}| z = \frac {1}{n} + \frac {i}{m} \ with \ \ m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash  \{ 0 \} \} $

---

Thoughts: $z:= a +bi$

- real part $a$ is  $\frac {1}{n}$ so I think it is bounded because $a \in [-1,1]$
- imaginary part $b$ is  $\frac {i}{m}=\frac {1}{m} * i$ so I think it is also bounded because $b \in [-i,i]$
- => both parts are bounded => $z$ is bounded too

---

1. Are my thougts correct?
2. How can I check if $M$ is closed?

Comment: the imaginary part id $b=\frac{1}{m}\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Make a sketch, and you should be able to find lots of limit points of $M$ that aren't in $M$. One will be especially evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for $M$ bounded. But an argument like:
$$\forall z\in M, z\in \overline B(0,1)=\{z\in\mathbb Z\mid |z|\leq1\}$$
would have been better. But anyway, you proved that $M\subset [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ which is good too.

But your set is not compact because $0\notin M$. Indeed, $0\in \overline M$ but not in $M$.